# Typescript Compiler Error "Generic type requires 0 type argument(s)"

Tags: typescript

(This is a follow up to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20332718/351836).)

I am trying to build a typescript definition file for an existing Javascript library. The difficulties I have are related to the combination of:

- nested types
- generics
- named constructors (which are very similar to nested types)

This is the code I'm trying to compile in a `lib.d.ts` library defintion file:

```
declare module MyModule {
    export class SomeClass<T> {
        new(); // default (unnamed) constructor for SomeClass
        static WithEnumValue: {  // "named constructor" for SomeClass
            new <T>(enumValue: MyModule.SomeClass.SomeEnum): SomeClass<T>;
        };
    }

    export module SomeClass {
        export enum SomeEnum { VALUE_A, B, C }
    }
}

declare module OtherModule {
    export interface OtherInterface {
        foo<T>(inst: MyModule.SomeClass<T>);
    }
}
```

The problem is the declaration of the generic method `foo` in the `OtherModule.OtherInterface`

Using the above code I get this strange compiler output (using tsc compiler 0.9.1.1):

`error TS2090: Generic type 'MyModule.SomeClass' requires 0 type argument(s).`

Obviously it is hard to declare a generic type with 0 type arguments, because neither `<>` nor the variant without type arguments `MyModule.SomeClass` will work - the latter will give this slightly contradicting error:

`error TS2173: Generic type references must include all type arguments.`

I can get it to compile if I declare the `OtherInterface` inside `MyModule` and leave away the module name, but the interface is in a different module in the real world.

How can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a compiler bug - the compiler isn't realising that you are trying to use the class named `SomeClass` rather than the module named `SomeClass`.

The good news is that your declaration is actually good and the next version of the compiler (0.9.5) will be perfectly happy with it.

You can [download the 0.9.5 beta](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/F/2FFA1FBA-97CA-4FFB-8ED7-A4AE06398948/TypeScriptSetup.0.9.5.beta.exe), which has some bug fixes and performance improvements (but is obviously a beta... but I'm using it and it seems stable).